# Trying to delay the start of a stopwatch

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to delay my stopwatch, and I don't know what's wrong with my code.

```
document.getElementById('start-test').onclick=function() {
    int=setInterval(timerUpdate,9);
    
}

function timerUpdate() {
    ms+=9
        if(ms>990) {
            ms=0
            s++
        }
        if (ms<10) {
            const milliseconds="00"+ms
            document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML=milliseconds
        }
        else if (ms<100) {
            const milliseconds="0"+ms
            document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML=milliseconds
        }
        else {
            const milliseconds=ms
            document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML=milliseconds
            
        }
        document.getElementById('s').innerHTML=s
}
setTimeout(timerUpdate,4000);
```

---

This is the code I used, which begins repeating every 0.009 seconds after I click the start button, but I want it to be delayed by 4 seconds. I added the setTimeout feature at the bottom to try to achieve this, however this isn't working. Pls help.

Comment: Intervals and timers in Javascript aren't precision timekeeping devices - quite the opposite - it calls them when it feels like it, and they are skidding all over the place in time. You should call `Date.now()` inside the timer handler, and use that to determine the passage of time. Counting callbacks with your fingers will be jittery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you should call `setTimeout` inside the `onclick` function, you can edit your code like this:

```js
document.getElementById('start-test').onclick = function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    int = setInterval(timerUpdate, 9);
  }, 4000);


}

function timerUpdate() {
  ms += 9
  if (ms > 990) {
    ms = 0
    s++
  }
  if (ms < 10) {
    const milliseconds = "00" + ms
    document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML = milliseconds
  } else if (ms < 100) {
    const milliseconds = "0" + ms
    document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML = milliseconds
  } else {
    const milliseconds = ms
    document.getElementById('ms').innerHTML = milliseconds

  }
  document.getElementById('s').innerHTML = s
}
```